# Convert Parquet FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY into a DECIMAL in native Java map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, mapreduce, parquet

My underlying data is written using HIVE output format (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat)

Trying to read this data using native Java Map reduce

```
byte[] b = value.getBinary(value.getType().getFieldIndex(field), 0).getBytes();

HiveDecimal hd = HiveDecimal.create(b, true);
```

value here is `org.apache.parquet.example.data.Group` type hd in this case becomes NULL.

But below works just fine for string/int types.

```
value.getValueToString(value.getType().getFieldIndex(field), 0);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to more clearly ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found a way by using DecimalUtils from 
Parquet Decimal Type to Java BigDecimal conversion in Pig.

Adding link
[Github link for DecimalUtils](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-pig/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/pig/convert/DecimalUtils.java)